# Update field based on spatial query (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-query

I was an intermediate user of MapInfo and have recently converted to QGIS. I would often use MapInfo to add a column in boundary file A saying which zone in boundary file B it is contained in. However, I cannot work out how to do this in QGIS.

---

Sorry, this is the error message I received when I tried to run the function.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: I've a nasty feeling that this is going to be one of those... "you can do this...if you install a PostGIS server" (but in the meantime, MapInfo SQL is actually quite good) questions.

Answer (score 6):

To add a column containing some attribute of a feature of another layer, with which there exists a topological relation:

1. Define a function: layer properties -> attributes -> field calculator -> function editor
2. Input code which does the work

Eg is_contained_in() returns the value from `column` of feature from B which contains feature A

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def is_contained_in(layername, column, feature, parent):
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        if feature.geometry().within(feat.geometry()):
            return feat[column]
```

[image: function]

3. Run the script and go to tab Expression
4. Create a new field, a virtual one if you like, and type in an expression like this:

[image: expression]

5. new field `contained_in` is added to the attribute table and hold the `fid` of a polygon of layer `B`

[image: new field]

Tested with this situation (labels - red: layer B/fid, black: layer A/contained_in):

[image: test case]

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I decided to go with the approach of creating a new function. However, it does not appear to work. I am trying to attached the field 'NAME' from the layer 'B'. However, I get the following error:

Comment: @James it seems that you haven't give a name for the new column. Please give a field name in the output field name text edit widget, and an appropriate field type. Then try again. If this doesn't help Post some details of your script please . Maybe there is an type error.

Comment: this did not work for me. Qgis keeps complaining that the function is being invoked with the wrong number of arguments

Comment: I tested this on QGIS 2.18.15. It should work since calculations are done on the fly. But it was only possible to me to label this informations, retrieving attribute table was only showing NULL values.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **Join attributes by location** tool.

Say you have the following layers:

- `layer_a` : the layer to which you want to attach attribute values from `layer_b`
- `layer_b` : the layer from which you want to take attribute values

Go to Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes by Location.

Then, set the parameters as below:

[image]

The tool will create a third layer (named `layer_c` here) which will be `layer_a` features combined to `layer_b` attributes. You eventually have to remove columns that you don't need and the job is done!

Feel free to test `Attribute Summary` and `Output table` options depending on what you want to achieve.

If you are intersecting a lines or polygons layer with a polygons layer, the program might give you 'bad' results for overlapping features (i.e. a line intersecting 2 polygons or a polygon intersecting 2 polygons). In that case, the program will select attributes from the polygon that is intersected by the biggest part of the line / polygon.

Comment: Attribiutes pulled in were all null...