# referencing to features geometry in an expression

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, expression, function, qgis-custom-function

I have a layerA with roads and a layerB with one shortest path.

If I put an aggregate function into a virtual field in layerB to calculate the sum of fieldAA where the shortest path contains features of layerA, it returns the sum of every feature in layerA.

I tried different expression and they returned all the same result (sum of every feature):

---

aggregate( 'layerA', 'sum', "fieldAA", contains($geometry, $geometry))

aggregate( 'layerA', 'sum', "fieldAA", contains(geometry($currentfeature), $geometry))

aggregate( 'layerA', 'sum', "fieldAA", within($geometry, geometry($currentfeature)))

---

In the documentation you find

[image]

So I was wondering to which geometry they both refer to and how I can perform an expression like `contains(geometry currentfeature layerA, geometry features layerB)`

Suggestions on how to get the same result with a custom pythoncode in the function editor are also welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, the filter expression (forth parameter of `aggregate`) can only access fields and values from the referenced layer (`'layerA'` in your example) and not from the layer you're going to store results into (i.e., `layerB`). One solution could be to use the Function Editor and write Python code.

Comment: how would such python code look like?

Comment: It would look as the solution given by Detlev here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178522/update-field-based-on-spatial-query-qgis, although the Python code there can be optimized with a spatial index. You could also have a look at the "Join attributes by location" tool, as explained by wiltomap in the same thread.

Comment: I know the 'join attributes by location', but I need contain, not intersect.  I tried Detlev's approach, but I have multiple items within 1 original.  So I need to sum them up.

Comment: Have a look at the Processing tool 'Join Attributes by Location', there you can select 'Contains'. I'll elaborate more on the Python approach, which I find very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the filter expression (fourth parameter of `aggregate`) can only access fields and values from the referenced layer (`layerA` in your example) and not from the layer you're going to store results into (i.e., `layerB`). Two possible solutions could be:

1. To use the `Join attributes by location` from Processing  (select `contains` as `Geometric predicate` and the value `sum` for `Statistics for summary`).
2. To use the `Function Editor` and use Python code.

I'll elaborate more on the second solution.

---

A function with the following parameters would be handy in your case:

- Name of the layer with all roads (`layerA` for you).
- Name of the field from `layerA` to aggregate (`fieldAA` for you).
- Current feature geometry (from layer with the shortest path).

So, go to `Field Calculator`, open the `Function Editor`, create a new file, and paste this code:

```py
from qgis.core import ( qgsfunction, QgsSpatialIndex, QgsFeatureRequest, 
    QgsMapLayerRegistry )

index_cache = {}

def get_layer_index( layer ):
    if layer.name() not in index_cache:
        index_cache[layer.name()] = QgsSpatialIndex( layer.getFeatures() )
    return index_cache[layer.name()]

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def sum_contains(road_layer_name, field_name, geometry, feature, parent):
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( road_layer_name )
    if not layers:
        raise Exception( "The layer could not be found." )
    layer = layers[0]
    intersectIds = get_layer_index( layer ).intersects( geometry.boundingBox() )
    features = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids( intersectIds ) )
    return sum( f[field_name] for f in features if geometry.contains(f.geometry()) )
```

Click on Load to register the functions above, go to the `Expression` tab and write this expression:

```
sum_contains( 'layerA', 'fieldAA',  $geometry )
```

Still in the `Field Calculator`, create/choose your target field (from `layerB`) and click `OK`.

You should get the sum of `fieldAA` from only those features in `layerA` contained by each feature in `layerB`.

---

*NOTE 1: The `sum_contains()` function uses a cache to avoid building the whole spatial index for each feature (source: [How to Use Function Editor in QGIS Field Calculator](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/06/05/qgis-function-editor/)).*

*NOTE 2: Once you use the aforementioned expression the cache is built for the road layer, so, if you edit features from such layer and you want to use the `sum_contains()` function again, you would need to go to `Function Editor`, select the file you created, and click on `Load` so that the index is initialized again. Otherwise, you would be using an outdated index.*

---

EDIT: Adding in-line comments to explain the code.

```py
from qgis.core import ( qgsfunction, QgsSpatialIndex, QgsFeatureRequest, 
    QgsMapLayerRegistry )

index_cache = {} # Global variable to store spatial index for layers

def get_layer_index( layer ):
    # Python function to check whether we already built an index for
    # a given layer. If so, just return the built index, otherwise
    # build it now and store it in the global variable for further calls.
    if layer.name() not in index_cache:
        index_cache[layer.name()] = QgsSpatialIndex( layer.getFeatures() )
    return index_cache[layer.name()]

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def sum_contains(road_layer_name, field_name, geometry, feature, parent):

    # First, check if we can access the road layer 
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( road_layer_name )
    if not layers:
        raise Exception( "The layer could not be found." )
    layer = layers[0]

    # Second, obtain ids of road features that intersect the
    # current geometry BBox. This uses a spatial index 
    # to optimize the spatial search. Features that intersect the BBox
    # likely intersect the geometry itself, but we need to check that later.
    intersectIds = get_layer_index( layer ).intersects( geometry.boundingBox() )

    # From the step above we get a list of matching feature ids,
    # Now we use them to request the feature objects.
    features = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids( intersectIds ) )

    # Now we perform a spatial search using the geometry predicate
    # 'contains' with current geometry and all features that 
    # intersect its BBox, because they are great candidates to match.
    # We do this in one line (see Python list comprehensions): 
    # iterate (road) features, validate the 'contains' predicate, 
    # and list field values of matching features. Finally, we sum 
    # the list of values and return the total.
    return sum( f[field_name] for f in features if geometry.contains(f.geometry()) )
```

Comment: Wonderfull.  It does what I was looking for.  I would like to use your answer as a base for learning pyqgis.  Can you break up your code and give some information about what the different codeblocks doeing?

Comment: I added a section with in-line comments to explain what the code does.

Comment: OK, I can start studying...